# Is it viable to boost capacitor voltage to improve energy density?

Tags: capacitor, switching, supercapacitor

Having a look at supercapacitors available on digikey they seem fairly expensive (say for example a capacitor with \$E = CV_{rated}^2 = 50 J\$ ).

However, an equivalent ceramic capacitor energy-wise costs far less; the problem being voltages on the kilovolt range \$V_{rated} = 2 kV\$.

Would it viable to replace supercapacitors with lower capacitance components together with some kind of boosting circuit? (presumably with a well thought out isolation)

Comment: Using 2kV, you still need 12.5uF to store 50J. That's still going to cost you a fair bit in [capacitors](https://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors/131083?k=&pkeyword=&FV=fff40002%2Cfff8000b%2C3800bd%2C3800c0%2C380132%2C3801f9%2C380306%2C3804da%2C380561%2C3805e1&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=-13&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25), though it will give you really good pulsed-power capabilities. Supercapacitors likely have a better cost for power density and would be easier to use.

Comment: @user2943160 Ah yes thanks, the price indeed is not lower seems I've missed a few orders of magnitude somewhere.

Comment: I don't know, but this may be helpful: The energy stored in a dielectric is a function of the electric field, and the volume of dielectric. For a given dielectric material, once it reaches its maximum field strength, you cannot increase energy density without increasing volume of dielectric. So at some point you will reach the volumetric capacity of the particular package you are considering. I assume super-caps have a special dielectric which gives them superior volumetric energy density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no.

To use some current Digikey parts/prices and the 50J storage requirement for *just* the capacitors:

- 50J using nominal 50% discharge of a 5.5V supercapacitor (no derating) requires \$\frac{50J}{5.5V^2 - 2.75V^2} \approx 2.2F\$

  - The [PHV-5R4H255-R](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/bussmann/Electronics/Resources/product-datasheets/bus-elx-ds-4403-phv-series.pdf) from Eaton is rated at 5.4V, 2.5F, and priced at [$11.90](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/eaton/PHV-5R4H255-R/283-4188-ND/3878056) quantity 1 on Digikey.
  - There are a variety of [other supercaps](https://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors/electric-double-layer-capacitors-supercaps/131084?FV=fff40002%2Cfff8000c%2C38001e%2C380029%2C3802da%2C3805e4&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=-13&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) at 5 to 5.6V and capacitance from 90F to 10mF
- 50J using nominal 100% of a 2.5kV ceramic capacitor (derate to 2kV) requires \$\frac{50J}{2000V^2}=12.5 \mu F\$

  - The [3640WC223KAT9A](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/AVX%20PDFs/High_Voltage_MLC_Chips.pdf) from AVX is rated at 2.5kV, 0.022µF, and priced at [$4.448](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/avx-corporation/3640WC223KAT9A/3640WC223KAT9A-ND/1455601) quantity 180: total cost of 568 capacitors is $2526.464. (!!)
  - Prices don't get much better and capacitance doesn't go up, but other [ceramic capacitor](https://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors/131083?k=&pkeyword=&pv7=3&pv7=2&pv7=17&pv7=292&FV=3801f9%2Cfff40002%2Cfff8000b&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=-13&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) can be considered

So, you might gain an exceptionally low ESR from having many ceramic capacitors, but they will be a challenge to assemble hundreds of components. Very specific pulsed applications may gain an advantage from chip or chassis-mount, high-voltage ceramic capacitors. However, for backup power in electronics, supercapacitors will have a much better value and energy density in comparison to high-voltage ceramic capacitors.